# How do get any exit code in bash when running a script inside a script?

Tags: bash, macos

I am trying to run a script where inside I run another script, after it has run I want to retrieve the exit code and do something with it but I only get `0` every time.

I also tried different approaches with sourcing it or wrapping the command in a function and had also given both execution rights with `chmod -x`.

a.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkdir data
mkdir -p data/test
```

b.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x

(bash a.sh) &
pid=$!

wait $pid
exitCode=$?

echo $pid
echo $exitCode
```

Result with `bash b.sh`:

```
+ pid=7399
+ wait 7399
+ bash a.sh
mkdir: data: File exists
+ exitCode=0
+ echo 7399
7399
+ echo 0
0
```

Result with `bash a.sh`:

```
mkdir: data: File exists (no exit code)
```

Result with `mkdir data`:

```
mkdir: data: File exists (exit code 1)
```

I know I can do `mkdir -p data` but this is just a test to get any exit code that I can work with later in my script.

Bash version: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)

Comment: Your example works and exits with code 1 in GNU bash, version 4.4.19

Comment: @AlfredE.Noobman can you test it with v.3.2.57. It is my default on macOS.

Comment: Ah got it, edited my post. In my script I had some command after that running which returned 0.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using: `set -e`

Reference: https://ss64.com/bash/set.html

This enables immediately exiting when something went wrong. In my case the second command returned 0 and that's why I got 0 every time.